# Why multiprocessing does not work?

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

I have this code:

```
import multiprocessing


def worker():
    print 'Worker'
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

For whatever reason it prints 'Worker' two times and stops. Does anyone know why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Tested on 2.7.10 and 3.5.2.... it works for me, can you give more details? Maybe version number, OS, etc etc...

Comment: It prints five times for me. Python 2.7. Maybe an environment issue?

Comment: This is not reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting multiprocessing tasks in Python on a defined value of "cores", you better choose to create a Pool and start the Process inside of that Pool.

```
 pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
 for i in range(5):
     pool.apply_async(worker)
 pool.close()
```

But if you like to do it on your way, I think you have to add a `p.join()`:

```
import multiprocessing


def worker():
    print 'Worker'
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start() 
        p.join()
```